# JQuery animate same item twice

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, element

I'm animating an image a certain amount from one menu button. It slides out per menu button. Then there's another link that when clicked the image needs to slide out more. This isn't happening.

Here's the jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#busoptbio").hide();
    $("#current").toggle(function() {
        $("#busoptbio").show();
        $("#busoptbio").animate({
            left: '+=348px'
        }, 1200);
    }, function() {
        $("#busoptbiolnk").click(function() {
            $("#busoptbio").animate({
                left: '+=550px'
            }, 1200); < ------2nd animate not working
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks so much,
Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are using the toggle function which binds two events to a single link, in your case this is the element with the ID `#current`. These events will only be called when you click on `#current`. You can't listen for a click inside of the toggle, which is already a listener on its own.

So if you want to have the second animation happen when you click "Meet the experts", you'll need to approach it differently:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#busoptbio").hide();
    $("#current").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#busoptbio").show();
        $("#busoptbio").animate({
            left: '+=348px'
        }, 1200);
    });

    $("#busoptbiolnk").click(function() { // When the link is clicked, the rest rolls out
        $("#busoptbio").animate({
            left: '+=550px'
        }, 1200);
    });
});
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

If youre gonna use a `<a>` as a trigger, be sure to either not define `href` or prevent the default event from being triggered (going to the link in href).

I have updated the code to prevent the default action, but as mentioned before this could also be solved by changing the `<a>`

Comment: When I add .click to the first section it doesn't work at all.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with the first section?

Comment: The reason it doesn't work for you is because you have 'href' defined of the link.. so it will activate that link and reload the page as opposed to execute the above code.

Comment: To get the animate to return after click just add another a {left: '-=550px'} because as it is it keep on going?

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the site, the animation works fine, the problem is your click event is on the div rather than the link. Go from: `$("#busoptbiolnk").click` to `$("#busoptbiolnk a").click` so that the `<a>` tag itself receives the click.

Tested in Chrome, on the second link click below the colored box instead of on the text.

EDIT:

I see that you added my suggestion, your problem is now the toggle as Joey says.  It now toggles if you click the 'Business Optimization services', click it again, and then click the link.  Remove the toggle and just bind the events without it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#busoptbio").hide();
  $("#current").click(function() {
    $("#busoptbio").show();
    $("#busoptbio").animate({left: '+=340px'}, 1200);
    return false;
  });
  $("#busoptbiolnk a").click(function(){
    $("#busoptbio").animate({left: '+=550px'}, 1200);
    return false;
  });
});
```

EDIT again:

your page gets redirected before the animation plays, add return false to the click handlers (as above) to fix.  Alternatively, set a#current's href to "#"

Comment: I have Joey's code with your $("#busoptbiolnk a").click  and it's not working at all

Comment: the page follows `a#current`'s href and refreshes the page, so it appears that it's doing nothing.  If you step through the code using firebug or the developer tools in chrome you can watch it expand and then reload the page.

Comment: I need the animate function to return when the tab link is clicked {left: '-=550px'} doesn't seem to work